# How to get particular level of category in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 i want to get level of category.

for example,
i have categogory tree like following

```
AllCategory->Mobile->samsung
AllCategory->Clothing->Men
AllCategory->Laptop->Dell
```

here i want to access second level category means Mobile,Clothing,Laptop

so how to do that

please help me
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: please post magento questions in http://magento.stackexchange.com/. so that somebody in future can depend only that site for his Q and A s.

Comment: @zamil I wouldn't recommend this, since a) magento.se is still Beta and b) afaik it's not thought for strictly programming-related questions. See http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/36

Comment: @JürgenThelen: it will soon be out of beta :)(hepefully). and magento.se is for everything related to magento.programming and usage

Comment: @zamil Nice to hear that it seems to be out of beta soon, but where did you get that "magento.se is about programming" from? Never seen that stated officially somewhere. Their [FAQ](http://magento.stackexchange.com/faq) states it's for "users". I fail to find the word "programming" in the whole FAQ. Or is this just your personal opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addIsActiveFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
```

basically add this `->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)`

Comment: i have used this code it will give me second level category twice for example it gives laptop, mobile,clothing two times..

Comment: yes, i have got solution thank you. i have used `foreach($categories as $cat)
  {
   echo "<pre>";
   echo ($cat->getName());
  }`

Comment: How can i get level 2 category list from db, how to run above code in sql.